# Azure VM Run Command using Python SDK executing but script doesnt run

Tags: python, sdk, azure-functions

I am writing an Azure Function using the Azure Python SDK to be able to execute a powershell script on a VM using a "Run Command" capability.

The issue is that everything shows as working but there is no trace of the powershell commands that i have been testing with inside the VM.

Code i have is:

```py
    import logging
    import azure.functions as func
    from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
    from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential

    def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
        logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    vm_name = req.params.get('vm_name')
    rg_name = req.params.get('rg_name')
   
    if not vm_name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            vm_name = req_body.get('vm_name')

    if vm_name:
        client_secret = "xxx"
        subscription_id = "xxxx"
        tenant_id = "xxxx"
        client_id ="xxxx"

        credentials = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret)

        run_command_name = "RunPowerShellScript"

        run_command = {
            'command_id': 'RunPowerShellScript',
            'location': 'australiaeast',
            'script': 'Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source   "RunCMDTest" -EventID 1 -EntryType Information -Message "Testing Run Command from Azure Function"',
                }
        compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
        runcmd = compute_client.virtual_machine_run_commands.begin_create_or_update(rg_name, vm_name, run_command_name, run_command)
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Executing test on VM {vm_name} in RG {rg_name}.")

    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )
```

When testing the function everything shows as successful - > output at the end of post.

If i look into the Activity Log of the VM, it shows as Accepted and Succeeded

[image]

I run the same command from the Azure Portal within the VM blade and it is successful

[image]

Any ideas as to why nothing is happening within the VM?

> *[2023-01-04T11:04:55.293Z] Request URL: 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxx-subidxxx/resourceGroups/xxxrgxxx/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/xxxvmxxx/runCommands/RunPowerShellScript?api-version=REDACTED'
> [2023-01-04T11:04:55.293Z] Request method: 'PUT'
> [2023-01-04T11:04:55.293Z] Request headers: [2023-01-04T11:04:55.293Z]
> 'Content-Type': 'application/json' [2023-01-04T11:04:55.293Z]
> 'Content-Length': '29' [2023-01-04T11:04:55.293Z]     'Accept':
> 'application/json, text/json' [2023-01-04T11:04:55.293Z]
> 'x-ms-client-request-id': '9e8fcfda-8c1f-11ed-b5f8-00224811eef0'
> [2023-01-04T11:04:55.293Z]     'User-Agent':
> 'azsdk-python-azure-mgmt-compute/29.0.0 Python/3.9.15
> (Linux-5.4.0-1094-azure-x86_64-with-glibc2.31)'
> [2023-01-04T11:04:55.293Z]     'Authorization': 'REDACTED'
> [2023-01-04T11:04:55.293Z] A body is sent with the request
> [2023-01-04T11:04:55.723Z] Response status: 200
> [2023-01-04T11:04:55.724Z] Response headers:
> [2023-01-04T11:04:55.724Z]     'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
> [2023-01-04T11:04:55.725Z]     'Pragma': 'no-cache'
> [2023-01-04T11:04:55.726Z]     'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'
> [2023-01-04T11:04:55.726Z]     'Content-Type': 'application/json;
> charset=utf-8' [2023-01-04T11:04:55.726Z]     'Content-Encoding':
> 'REDACTED' [2023-01-04T11:04:55.726Z]     'Expires': '-1'
> [2023-01-04T11:04:55.726Z]     'Vary': 'REDACTED'
> [2023-01-04T11:04:55.727Z]     'Azure-AsyncOperation': 'REDACTED'
> [2023-01-04T11:04:55.727Z]     'Azure-AsyncNotification': 'REDACTED'
> [2023-01-04T11:04:55.727Z]     'x-ms-ratelimit-remaining-resource':
> 'Microsoft.Compute/UpdateVM3Min;237,Microsoft.Compute/UpdateVM30Min;1193'
> [2023-01-04T11:04:55.727Z]     'Strict-Transport-Security': 'REDACTED'
> [2023-01-04T11:04:55.728Z]     'x-ms-request-id':
> 'c735cde5-a228-418d-a856-856dd0fc1a16' [2023-01-04T11:04:55.728Z]
> 'Server': 'Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0, Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0'
> [2023-01-04T11:04:55.728Z]
> 'x-ms-ratelimit-remaining-subscription-writes': '1194'
> [2023-01-04T11:04:55.728Z]     'x-ms-correlation-request-id':
> 'REDACTED' [2023-01-04T11:04:55.729Z]     'x-ms-routing-request-id':
> 'REDACTED' [2023-01-04T11:04:55.729Z]     'X-Content-Type-Options':
> 'REDACTED' [2023-01-04T11:04:55.729Z]     'Date': 'Wed, 04 Jan 2023
> 11:04:55 GMT' [2023-01-04T11:04:55.739Z] Executed
> 'Functions.func-execute_system_test' (Succeeded,
> Id=f0f0fa80-c8e1-4d59-a1e1-e40ef75c39e2, Duration=958ms)

Comment: It is very hard to read your question because of spurious  backticks and other formatting issues. Please format it for better readability. You can refer [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: @MattAuer, Could you provide the answer how you fixed it so it would be beneficial to the other community members who are facing the similar issue

Comment: Sorry, meant the formatting is fixed

Answer (score 0):

Quick update, i have managed to find out the issue. It was the structure of the run_command. Originally i had it

```
 run_command = {
            'command_id': 'RunPowerShellScript',
            'location': 'australiaeast',
            'script': 'Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source   "RunCMDTest" -EventID 1 -EntryType Information -Message "Testing Run Command from Azure Function"',
                }
```

However after diving deep through the Python SDK doco (specifically https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/azure.mgmt.compute.v2022_08_01.models.virtualmachineruncommand?view=azure-python and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/azure.mgmt.compute.v2022_08_01.models.virtualmachineruncommandscriptsource?view=azure-python) it should be structured like this:

```
   run_command = {
            'command_id': 'RunPowerShellScript',
            'location': 'australiaeast',
            'source': {
                'script': 'Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source "RunCMDTest" -EventID 1 -EntryType Information -Message "Testing Run Command from Azure Function"'
                }
        }
```

Hopefully this helps someone in the future!